# How can I remove duplicated code between classes?

Tags: java, dry

I have 2 class: RecursiveFibonacci and MemorizedRecursiveFibonacci. This is what I have so far.

**RecursiveFibonacci Class**

```
public class SimpleRecursiveFibonacci {

  public BigInteger fibonacci(int n) {
    if(n < 2) {
      return BigInteger.ONE;             
    }

    return fibonacci(n - 2).add(fibonacci(n - 1));
  }
}
```

**and MemorizedRecursiveFibonacci Class**

```
public class MemoizedRecursiveFibonacci {
  private Map<Integer, BigInteger> cache = new HashMap<>();

  public BigInteger fibonacci(int n) {
    if(n < 2) {
      return BigInteger.ONE;
    }
    if(!cache.containsKey(n)){
      BigInteger currentFibonacci = fibonacci(n - 2).add(fibonacci(n - 1));
      cache.put(n, currentFibonacci);
    }

    return cache.get(n);
  }
}
```

As I see, there are some duplicated code in MemorizedRecursiveFibonacci Class

```
 if(n < 2) {
      return BigInteger.ONE;
```

and

```
  BigInteger currentFibonacci = fibonacci(n - 2).add(fibonacci(n - 1));
```

How can I keep it DRY? remove duplicated code?

Comment: What about using MemoizedRecursiveFibonacci  and implement a method like public BigInteger fibonacci(int n, bool useCache) and lets the caller to use the cache or not? Or using an attribute @Cacheable to decorate the method to mantain a cache?

Comment: An unrelated observation: the memoized version always populates the HashMap with consecutive Integer keys. Therefore it would be more efficient to use an ArrayList and use the index instead of the key.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
public class SimpleRecursiveFibonacci {

    /** Gets the fibonacci value for n */
    public final BigInteger fibonacci(int n) {
        if (n == 0) {
            return BigInteger.ZERO;
        } else if (n == 1) {
            return BigInteger.ONE;
        }
        return getFibonacci(n);
    }

    /** Recursively calculates the fibonacci by adding the two previous fibonacci. */
    protected final BigInteger calculateFibbonacci(int n) {
        return fibonacci(n - 2).add(fibonacci(n - 1));
    }

    /** 
     * Somehow get the fibonacci value for n.
     * Could be by calculation, getting it from a cache, or anything.
     * Defaults to calculation.
     */
    protected BigInteger getFibonacci(int n) {
        return calculateFibbonacci(n);
    }

}

public class MemoizedRecursiveFibonacci extends SimpleRecursiveFibonacci {

    // Cache using an array list as recommended by user @DodgyCodeException
    private ArrayList<BigInteger> cache = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected BigInteger getFibonacci(int n) {
        if (cache.size() < n) {
            BigInteger fib = calculateFibbonacci(n);
            cache.add(fib);
            return fib;
        } else {
            return cache.get(n - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Maybe this is an option... but not the best i think.

```
public class SimpleRecursiveFibonacci {

public BigInteger fibonacci(int n) {
    if(n < 2) {
        return BigInteger.ONE;
    }
    return calculate(n);
}

protected BigInteger calculate(int n){
    return fibonacci(n - 2).add(fibonacci(n - 1)),
}
```

}

```
public class MemoizedRecursiveFibonacci extends SimpleRecursiveFibonacci{
private Map<Integer, BigInteger> cache = new HashMap<>();

@Override
protected BigInteger calculate(int n) {
    if(!cache.containsKey(n)){
        BigInteger currentFibonacci = super.calculate(n);
        cache.put(n, currentFibonacci);
    }
    return cache.get(n)
}
```

}

Comment: It's not bad actually. Classic template method :) Only improvement I'd make is to return `currentFibonacci` early instead of looking it up again.

Comment: Similar to what I came up with. I use a third method for how to "get" the fibonacci value, either from a cache or by recalculating it.

Answer (score 3):

Another example using Java 8 features - [`BiFunction`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiFunction.html) interface with lambda expression:

```
BiFunction<Fibonacci, Integer, BigInteger> func = (fibonacci, n) -> {
    if (n < 2) {
        return BigInteger.ONE;
    }
    return fibonacci.calc(n - 2).add(fibonacci.calc(n - 1));
};

new CachedFibonacci(func).calc(100);
```

Implementation:

```
interface Fibonacci {
    BigInteger calc(int n);
}

class SimpleFibonacci implements Fibonacci {

    private BiFunction<Fibonacci, Integer, BigInteger> fibonacci;

    SimpleFibonacci(BiFunction<Fibonacci, Integer, BigInteger> fibonacci) {
        this.fibonacci = fibonacci;
    }

    public BigInteger calc(int n) {
        return fibonacci.apply(this, n);
    }
}

class CachedFibonacci implements Fibonacci {

    private BiFunction<Fibonacci, Integer, BigInteger> fibonacci;
    private Map<Integer, BigInteger> cache = new HashMap<>();

    CachedFibonacci(BiFunction<Fibonacci, Integer, BigInteger> fibonacci) {
        this.fibonacci = fibonacci;
    }

    public BigInteger calc(int n) {
        if (!cache.containsKey(n)) {
            cache.put(n, fibonacci.apply(this, n));
        }
        return cache.get(n);
    }
}
```

Comment: This works, it does what it is supposed to do, but I find it a bit hard to follow. It seems to trade reduced readability for removing duplication.

Answer (score -2):

use static method:

```
public class SimpleRecursiveFibonacci {

  public static BigInteger fibonacci(int n) {
    if(n < 2) {
      return BigInteger.ONE;             
    }

    return fibonacci(n - 2).add(fibonacci(n - 1));
  }
}

public class MemoizedRecursiveFibonacci {
  private Map<Integer, BigInteger> cache = new HashMap<>();

  public BigInteger fibonacci(int n) {
    if(!cache.containsKey(n)){
      BigInteger currentFibonacci = SimpleRecursiveFibonacci.fibonacci(n);
      cache.put(n, currentFibonacci);
    }
    return cache.get(n);
  }
}
```

Comment: This will only memoize the final value, and not intermediate ones.